# Tagging on a specific branch in BitBucket Pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

So I know with BitBucket pipelines I can target tags and branches individually but I can't seem to figure out from the documentation how to make tags specific to a branch. This way if someone uses the tag on a different branch it doesn't trigger the build pipeline as it is on an incorrect branch.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a built-in way to do that, but you can still do it explicitly, like this:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          script:
            - 'TAG=$(git tag -l --points-at HEAD)'
            - 'if [ "$TAG" == "expected-tag" ]; then'
            - ./a-script-or-some-more-steps.sh
            - fi
```

(Untested, but basically this should work.)